# How to replace specific entries in a column using replace() in a dataframe when they are not getting updated in the output by using replace method.?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science

```
Here is a dataframe named Energy which looks like this:       
    Country                  Energy Supply      Energy Supply per Capita
16  Afghanistan              3.210000e+08       10.0    
17  Albania                  1.020000e+08       35.0    
18  Algeria                  1.959000e+09       51.0    
19  American Samoa           NaN                                        
40  Bolivia                  3.360000e+08       32.0
... ... ... ...
180 Republic of Korea        1.100700e+10       221.0   
213 Switzerland              1.113000e+09       136.0   
214 Syrian Arab Republic     5.420000e+08       28.0    
215 Tajikistan               1.060000e+08       13.0    
216 Thailand                 5.336000e+09       79.0    
228 Ukraine                  4.844000e+09       107.0
230 United Kingdom of 
    Great Britain and 
    Northern I...            7.920000e+09       124.0   
231 United Republic of Tanzania 9.940000e+08    20.0    
232 United States of America    9.083800e+10    286.0       

Energy=pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls')
Energy=Energy[(Energy.index>15)&(Energy.index<243)]

I needed to replace name of countries like "United States of America" to 
"United States","United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland" to 
"United Kingdom".  
I used the following code:

Energy['Country']=Energy.Country.str.strip('123.!?\n\t')
Energy['Country'].replace({'United States of America':'United 
States','United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland':'United 
Kingdom'},inplace=True)
```

But the name of countries is not getting updated in the output. I can't figure out where i am wrong. 
It is not working whether i am using split method or not.

Somebody please help.

Comment: This method should work. Maybe the values you're providing in replace function is not matching exactly with the column values. You can try giving regex=True if you're skeptical about it.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks a lot @LazyCoder